# STL c++ algorithm

Tags: c++, случайные-числа, stl

Подготовить анонимный метод gen, который бы возвращал при
каждом вызове случайное число, найденное STL-механизмом генерации
случайных чисел. Распределение: гауссово. Математическое ожидание: 12.
Нормальное отклонение 8.
случайное число должно быть типа double.Как ему задать гауссово распределение и мат. ожидание с отклонением. Снизу код на нормальное распределение для рандомных интов

```
auto gen = []() {
    std::mt19937 rng{std::random_device()()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(-50, 50);
    return distr(rng);
};
```

Comment: std::normal_distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы делал так -

```
auto gen = []() {
    static std::mt19937 rng{std::random_device()()};
    static std::normal_distribution<double> distr(12, 8);
    return distr(rng);
};
```

потому что в вашем варианте генератор создается заново всякий раз, и смысла в этом нет - если `random_device` не является истинным случайным генератором (а он, согласно стандарту, может и не быть таковым...), окажется, что вы возвращаете все время одно и то же значение. А если истинный - то его можно использовать непосредственно, а не для зерна.